# Odds ratio and prevalence of an outcome

Tags: self-study, odds-ratio, epidemiology

If someone could help me out, I'm confused with a finding in a paper:

> In a group of rural children with obesity there was a greater rise in
>   prevalence in obese children from 1 year to the next one when compared
>   to the urban group, but the OR for obesity in the former group was
>   lower than in the latter group.

I don't understand how can you get a greater prevalence of a condition and at the same time a lower risk for developing it.

Comment: For context you should provide a link to the paper.   I think it might be like when an epidemic reaches a peak the number of people with the disease is high but because it stops spresding the risk goes down.

Comment: It´s not published, it is a kind of "case study" that we are reviewing in class. Thanks for your viewpoint, I haven´t considered before.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that the answer is this: there was a greater *rise* in prevalence in the rural group, which means that **the proportion of people with obesity went up more in the rural group than in the urban group**, but the OR was less in the rural group, which means that the **proportion of people with obesity in the rural group was still less then in the urban group**.

Example:

Suppose there are $3$ people in the rural group and $6$ people in the urban group and the numbers with obesity are:

```
         rural     urban
year 1   1         4 
year 2   2         5
```

The rise in prevalence in rural is $2/3 - 1/3 = 1/3$. The rise in prevalence in urban is $5/6 - 4/6 = 1/6$, which is less. But the prevlance (and therefore the OR) is still higher in the urban group ($5/6 > 2/3$).

Comment: Thank you for the example, it clarifies the concept for me.  But in terms of clinical significance (not statistical),  I would think that this "low" OR in the rural group is a little misleading because the rise is greater than in the urban group, so I could deduce this group needs more interventions for prevention of  obesity.   Is that a valid assumption?